# Why the nested component won't render?

Tags: reactjs, components

I am trying to insert Item component into the main one, but it is not rendering. If I insert content of the component directly into RenderItems - it works. What's wrong?

```
const Item = (id, text) => {
    <div>
    <p>{id}</p>
    <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
};

class RenderItems extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items_array: [{id: 1, text: "text1"}, {id: 2, text: "text2"}, {id: 3, text: "text3"}],
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>   
                {this.state.items_array.map(i => <Item id={i.id} text={i.text} /> )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It works:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>   
            {this.state.items_array.map(i => {
            <div>   
                <p>{i.id}</p>
                <p>{i.text}</p>
            </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

the item function requires a return and also import as props not directly making the function

```
const Item = ({id, text}) => {
    return (<div>
    <p>{id}</p>
    <p>{text}</p>
    </div>)
};
```

OR

use parenthesis instead of curly braces like this:-

```
const Item = (id, text) => (
    <div>
    <p>{id}</p>
    <p>{text}</p>
    </div> );
```

Comment: you can actually omit the return if you want  `... = ({id, text}) => (<div ....)`

Comment: added it in the edit. 
also he was using curly braces which requires return

Comment: You don't even need the braces for your second example, in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

You may have learned that arrow functions imply the "return" statement, but they do only if you leave out the curly brackets, but you need curly brackets for React's JSX, so you have to write an explicit "return" [as answered by Adarsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305539/15979256).

Comment: you can still return objects if you use parentheses  `=> ({h:'a'});` and you can also omit the return in the Item  `=> ( <div> ... </div>)`.